# Calculate Real Time, Time spent on CPU, User Space Time, Kernal Space Time in C for my Program

Tags: c, linux, time

As mentioned in the title I am trying to find the different times listed below for my process:

Wall Time Spent Executing - The amount of time the process spent from start to finish. (i.e. the Real Time)

Total Time Spent on CPU - The amount of time the process spent executing instructions on the CPU plus the amount of time that the kernel was doing work on behalf of the process. (i.e. the Profile Time)

Time Spent in User Space - The amount of time the process spent executing instructions on the CPU. (i.e. the Virtual Time)

Time Spent in Kernel Space - The amount of time the kernel spent doing work on behalf of the process.

While searching I have found information on **linux perf** but I am unsure on how to use the package.

Comment: [time](https://linux.die.net/man/1/time).

Comment: I'd just use the `time` command, like `time ./myprog`.

Comment: I am trying to determine the length of time for my fibonacci function to run. However this function can be ran for multiple different values and I would like to store the time it takes for each input. Would I be able to store each of the different times into a variable? @kaylum

Comment: @tadman if you can answer the question also

Comment: Then please update your question to clarify that you want function level times. That's not what it says at the moment. And no, `time` can't do that. Also, update your question to clearly state whether you want an external tool or whether adding code into your program is ok.

Comment: If you're willing to instrument your code with special calls [what I'd do], you could have a look at `getitimer/setitimer` syscalls. But, most of the time spent will be in your user process, so, what I usually use is `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)`

Comment: But, what you may really want is the `times` syscall which gives system and user times for the process.